# in k8s cant load dump db to postgres for init it

Tags: kubernetes, postgresql

I have a k8s cluster for educational purposes. It has postgres one pod, but I can't load or dump db to postgres to initialise it.

I added a pv and pvc for `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and added `locate dump.sql` to it.

The postgres pod and service in k8s work, the database exists, but doesn't have tables. If I do `cat dump.sql | kubectl  exec -t postgres -- psql -U postgres -d postgres` works just fine.

The same construction works in docker with tables lost, but I can add sleep 60 between creating container and loading dump this work carrefully. can I add sleep between creating pod in k8s and loading dump from pv?